# How to split all columns and extract in each row using awk/unix commands?

Tags: awk

I have a tab-delim file with unequal number of columns in each row as shown below:

```
1_20_50_x_y_d    1_39_60_x_y_z    1_25_50_d_f_g    1_30_55_e_f_g
1_10_50_x_y_d    1_29_60_x_y_z    1_30_70_d_f_g
1_20_50_x_y_d    1_39_80_x_y_z
```

For each column, i need to extract the first three elements separated by "_" and need to write the min and max value from the 2nd and 3rd element among all columns. The first column remains the same as the 1st element. The output looks like:

```
1   20    60
1   10    70
1   20    80
```

Comment: Are the tab separated elements always 6 elements separated by an underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,f,/_/)
        if (i == 1) {
            key = f[1]
            min = max = f[2]
        }
        min = (f[2] < min ? f[2] : min)
        min = (f[3] < min ? f[3] : min)
        max = (f[2] > max ? f[2] : max)
        max = (f[3] > max ? f[3] : max)
    }
    print key, min, max
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1       20      60
1       10      70
1       20      80
```

I recommend you (and everyone else manipulating text) read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.